# Simple makefile for rendering templates

Tags: templates, makefile, gnu-make, erb

I want to have the simplest possible Makefile, so with `make` (no arguments) all *.erb templates in current directory will be rendered out, dropping the template extension. This is what I came up with so far:

```
INPUTS = $(wildcard *.erb)
all: $(INPUTS:.erb=)

%: %.erb
    cp  $@ $@.old 2>/dev/null || true
    erb  -T - $< > $@
```

Why doesn't just the target notation work standalone or e.g. `all: $($(wildcard *.erb):.erb=)`?
Is there a way to achieve this shorter / more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `$($(wildcard *.erb):.erb=)` doesn't work because the `$(...:...)` format is *variable* substitution, not *string* substitution.  In other words, the thing on the left side of the `:` is the *name* of a variable to be expanded, not a string.

So `$($(wildcard *.erb):...)` will first run the wildcard and substitute the results, then treat that as the **name** of a variable to be substituted.  Which clearly there is no variable with that name, so it expands to the empty string.

If you don't want the `INPUTS` variable you can use the `basename` function:

```
all: $(basename $(wildcard *.erb))
```

As to whether it's "more elegant", that's in the eye of the beholder and so not really something SO can help with.